# CMake 3.8+: Setting different compiler flags for projects that include both .cpp (C++) and .cu (CUDA) files

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I have a CMake project which includes a single target that includes both C++(`.cpp`) and CUDA C++(`.cu`) files. However I have some questions which I failed to address.

At the top of my `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
project(my-project CUDA CXX)
```

For the ones confused: Yes, CMake 3.8 makes CUDA C++ an intrinsically supported language. So there is no longer need to use things like `cuda_add_executable()` and sorcery like that. Everything works just fine by using standard and native CMake commands. Also, apparently you can set more than one languages in CMake's `project()` command. See: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/building-cuda-applications-cmake/

My problem now is that I want to set different compiler flags for the different compilers in a CMake way (i.e., with the `target_compile_options()` command). The first solution I can think of is:

```
add_compile_options(my_target
    PRIVATE
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-Wsign-conversion>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-arch=compute_30>
)
```

However, I find this code a bit ugly. The other option I can think of would be to create two separate targets, one for the `.cpp` files and one for the `.cu` files. Then I will be able to set the compiler options separately for the GCC and NVCC targets.

Both of the above solutions seem to work, but I am trying to figure out which is the better way. Any suggestions? Pros and cons?

I am also having trouble with the first solution when I want to include multiple compiler flags. What is the proper way of splitting them? Just use space between the different flags? And what if I want to span the expression on multiple lines? If I try to do so in any way, CMake gives me syntax errors.

Finally, I want to avoid manually altering `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Both solutions seems fine to me. I would use the one you suggested over different targets for `.cu`and `.cpp` files, to keep the complexity down and avoid inconsistencies in the linking stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @OutOfBound in comments, the simplest solution is to split your code in sub project(s). This way you can control each project flags independently, and even build multiple `.cu` files with different flags (if needed). If this becomes more complex, you might also want to build kernels with `nvcc` and load them with `cuModuleLoad*()`.